# How can I find out in which distributions a package is available?

Tags: package-management, distributions

From the search results I was able to get so far my question seems unlikely, although I don't know why ;-)

I'm writing an installation guide for a program and need a “compatibility matrix” for several packages on the different distributions. So what I need is the information in which distributions and releases a given package X is available, optionally together with the version.

Of course each distribution has a package index like [Debian Packages Search](https://packages.debian.org/index) from where I can get the information for this distribution. But is there an index or a search engine anywhere that can give me this information for many (all?) distributions?

Comment: There isn't, though someone set up something like that a few years ago - see [byacc summary](https://web.archive.org/web/20120509172313/http://oswatershed.org/pkg/byacc) on the Web Archive for example.

Comment: `rmadison` may be of use for Debian and its ilk - http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/rmadison.1.html

Answer (score 2):

[Repology](https://repology.org/) is an online service which seems to fit the bill. Its information is accurate for the packages I checked, but other commentators differ.

You might also find [`whohas`](https://github.com/whohas/whohas) useful. This is a tool which runs locally and interrogates a number of package indexes directly.

Both tools track most of the major distributions; Repology indexes lots of smaller ones too.

[Can I depend?](https://canidepend.com) provides a list of supported versions for a small set of language runtimes on a few distributions (Debian, Ubuntu, RHEL, SLES). Its scope is much smaller than Repology’s but it could be sufficient for some readers.

Comment: Interesting, but comparing with my programs, the first is noticeably inaccurate (I'm not going to use it).   The other would take more time to investigate.

Comment: For which packages did you find errors? I looked at [xterm](https://repology.org/metapackage/xterm/versions) among others and the results seem accurate. (I’m not trying to argue, I’m genuinely curious.)

Comment: I started with luit, and saw that some of my work was misattributed, looked at cdk (wrong version numbers).  Commenting now, there's bogus information for bcpp, vttest.  Also, judging by the results, it's Linux-specific, which is misleading since it implies more independence across packagers than exists, and ignores the other 60% of the packaging domain.

Comment: Oh OK, I see, thanks. It does have info on MacPorts, FreeBSD ports, and OpenIndiana, so it’s not Linux-specific, but most of the results are for Linux distributions.

Comment: See the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/repology/repology) for coverage details.

Answer (score 0):

[Distrowatch](https://www.distrowatch.com/) offers a list of installed packages for each distro. [For example (look at the tables in the middle of the page)](https://www.distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=mint)

Comment: I have found the [search page](https://www.distrowatch.com/search.php) on Distrowatch which is actually the functionality I need. Unfortunately it only tracks a certain number of packages - and (of course) the packages I'm interested in aren't among them.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

Get repos that have libmtp in version 1.1.19

```bsh
$ curl -s https://repology.org/api/v1/project/libmtp | jq -c '.[] | select( .version == "1.1.19" ) | .repo'`
"slackware64_current"
"slackwarearm_current"
"alpine_edge"
"alpine_edge"
"alpine_edge"
"altsisyphus"
"arch"
"artix"
"debian_12"
"debian_testing"
"debian_unstable"
"slackware_current"
"devuan_unstable"
"gentoo"
"homebrew"
"kali_rolling"
"kaos"
"liguros_stable"
"openindiana"
"liguros_develop"
"manjaro_stable"
"manjaro_staging"
"manjaro_testing"
"manjaro_unstable"
"openmamba"
"opensuse_tumbleweed"
"parabola"
"pisi_main"
"raspbian_testing"
"t2"
"ubuntu_22_04"
```

- https://repology.org/api
- https://gist.github.com/ipbastola/2c955d8bf2e96f9b1077b15f995bdae3#gistcomment-2708458
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47421993/get-specific-key-value-pairs-with-jq/47422094#47422094
- [jq Cheet Sheet](https://gist.github.com/olih/f7437fb6962fb3ee9fe95bda8d2c8fa4)