# finding a package and what version is in various distributions (stable release)

Tags: debian, ubuntu, package-management, compiling, bsd

I am looking to know about a package and what version is it across various distributions. I thought distrowatch might be the answer, but I found it tracks only 224 packages at the most. See https://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=compare-packages. Does anybody know of any site/service which I could use for the same?  It would be nice if the site has curl support on the lines of curl wttr.in/pune, not really a deal-breaker but would be nice if there is.

Comment: See [How can I find out in which distributions a package is available?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/417128/86440) (I’m avoiding an official dupe suggestion because that would hammer this question closed).

Comment: I was looking for distributions which have tome2 https://git.net-core.org/tome/t-engine4 but unfortunately the resource/s you provided don't seem to have tome2 or t-engine4 in their repo. so very difficult to know which distribution have it in their repo. before I ask about having it in Debian All the other requirements seem  to in Debian.

Comment: Right, no distribution carries Tales of Maj’Eyal. It does look interesting though, please file an RFP ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt see https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-games/2020/03/msg00002.html  . I am going to upstream to reply to that, see if somebody does.

Answer (score 0):

Only looking at current package list of the interesing distributions can answer that correctly, and up to date.

But note that if the distribution ships package version 5.5, it doesn't mean it doesn't contain lots of backported (or specifically developed) fixes, and is in some aspects near 5.8 (and others bog 5.5). "Enterprise" distributions are notorious for keeping a base version with many patches, for ultimate stability. Thus the versions you get can be right on to quite misleading. Specially in the "security vulnerabilities" department the base version is probably way off.